# AuthenticationStatusCode for SMSAuthentication for DocuSign Connect API

Tags: docusignapi

If we select Signer Authentication Options as SMS Authentication, the recipient is presented with a request page and must select a phone number to use for authentication.
After clicking Send SMS, a SMS text message with a passcode is sent to the recipient. The recipient enters the code and clicks Confirm Code to complete the security request. 
The recipient has three attempts to enter the code correctly.
If Confirm code is entered incorrectly,we are trying to track with trigger event "Recipient Authentication Failure" for Docusign Connect [setting screenshot mentioned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/unB1I.png).

What is authenticationstatuscode for SMS Authentication?
For e.g.,We have observed "PhoneAuthResult" for Phone authentication as part of Docusign connect response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is nothing in the Connect message that has the SMSAuth result like there is for phone auth. However, it is something in the pipeline and hopefully will ship sometime in 2016.